# How do I pass an array to a method that accepts an attribute with a splat operator?

Tags: ruby, splat

If I have a method like:

```
def sum *numbers
  numbers.inject{|sum, number| sum += number}
end
```

How would I be able to pass an array as numbers?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :044 > sum 1,2,3   #=> 6
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :045 > sum([1,2,3])   #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that I can't change the sum method to accept an array.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just put a splat when calling the method?

```
sum(*[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean this?

```
sum(*[1,2,3])
```

@Dogbert was first